# How multiple developers can work on a single Moodle project?

Tags: php, networking, development-environment, moodle

I am new to software development, working on creating a Moodle LMS project. I have already installed XAMPP and working on Moodle. But I have another 5 team members working on the same Moodle project.

As XAMPP is installed on everyone's computer, we are working separately. But I want to know how all we 6 developers can work in a team to develop a project. How can I go for making the network configurations? Do I need to share the XAMPP folder to all other team members in to work as a team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moodle already uses [git](https://git-scm.com/) for core development, that would certainly be your best bet for coordinating the code between multiple developers. See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Git_for_developers for more details (although that is a bit more focussed on contributing back patches to Moodle core).

Sharing the data is more difficult, but in my experience it usually works OK for each developer to work with their own Moodle install, with a central install for testing (and make sure each developer uses the xmldb editor to define install.xml + upgrade.php steps, so that the other developers can pull the latest code from them and the database definitions will be upgraded properly).

Answer (score 0):

Use any flavor of source distributed version control system, like [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [subversion](https://subversion.apache.org).